# Access denied (insufficient permissions) for escpos python Windows 7

Tags: python, errno, escpos

I am trying to access a RONGTA 328 printer using escpos in Python 3.7. I am using Anaconda3 in windows7. When I run the following code snippet I am getting [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions) error.

```
from escpos import *
p = printer.Usb(0x0fe6, 0x811e)
p.text("Hello world")
p.cut()
```

I found several solutions on the Internet but all are for Linux. What is the solution for Windows?

Comment: I often see questions like this on this site. Most devices on Windows will have a serial port driver. The ESCPOS library will also support both USB and serial. So why try to use the low-level USB mechanism? It would be much easier to use the ESCPOS library with PySerial using the serial port device driver provided by the printer vendor and its mode settings. Please give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for your nice suggestion. Will it work using a USB port or I should use using the serial port of a desktop PC?

Comment: There seems to be no USB virtual COM, so it will be connected via the DSUB9 serial port. If the 19200bps you can achieve is slow, why not switch to the TCP/IP 9100 port? Instead, the current situation may be affected by having device drivers and tools installed as USB printers and Windows desktop printers(page printers). If you uninstall all such software, you may be able to use it in Python. Please give it a try.